# Delphi - OSX - How to extend NSWindowDelegate

Tags: macos, cocoa, delphi

The current NSWindowDelegate implementation in Delphi is very limited. It doesn't include events such as [windowWillResize:toSize:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillResize:toSize:)

How can I extend it? I can see the code in source\rtl\osx'Macapi.Appkit.pas so I tried to make a copy of that file to my application folder and include it in the project.

However, after doing that I get lots of:

```
Unit FMX.[unit-name-here] was compiled with a different version of FMX.[other-unit-name-here].
```

What would be the appropriate way to extend it? How can I get rid of those errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own interface that adds the missing methods.

```
  NSWindowDelegateEx = interface(IObjectiveC)
    [{ Press Ctrl+Shift+G to insert a guid here }]
    procedure windowDidEnterFullScreen(notification: NSNotification); cdecl;
    function window(window: NSWindow; willUseFullScreenContentSize: NSSize): NSSize; cdecl; overload;
    function window(window: NSWindow; willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions): NSApplicationPresentationOptions; cdecl; overload;
  end;
```

When implementing the class that needs these additional methods, simply add your interface in addition to the interface that comes with Delphi.

```
  TMyWindowDelegate = class(TOCLocal, NSWindowDelegate, NSWindowDelegateEx)
  // ...
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of the error copy also the FMX.[other-unit-name-here] file to your project folder. It need to be recompiled because you have changed some interface.

Comment: In reality there will likely be many dependent units. They'd all need to be recompiled.